# How to have an array of integer pairs sorted by both integers while still correlating them in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting

I am using `C` but I am open to `C++` as well.

I have a set of data in forms of pairs of integers like {1,1}{600,2}{10,4} etc.
 Lets call them {a,b}. I am using an array like `arr[N][2]` to store the data.

The array is already sorted by `b`. I need to check a condition on `ai` and find first `ai` which satisfies a condition.

A simple method would be to start checking from i=0 to i=N linearly. But this doesn't take advantage of the fact that if the condition fails for a specific value of `a` say 10, then only values that may pass the test are those greater than `a`, that is greater than 10.

Maybe I should have a copy of array sorted by `a`, so that when a condn fails for some value of `a`, I can check for value of `a` greater than failed value. 
But how do I corelate the arrays so that a pair in one array can be found in other array?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by _ai_. But do you wish to search a pair `{a,b}` in an array of pairs _effectively_ ?

Comment: @P0W I think the op means the value of "a" in the i-th pair, i.e., a_i.

Comment: @P0W I have array pairs {a,b} and i is counter. so ai will be [0][a], [1][a], [2][a] and so on. what lightalchemist said is correct

Comment: Similar to the C++ answer, rather than duplicating an entire second copy of the array, you could create an array of pointers storing pointers to the original array in sort order for `a`. Then find the index for the `i-th` value in `a` that causes problems (save the index) and for your queries loop of the array of pointers from `index < n`. (although, depending on `sizeof int` and pointer size, you may not save any space over full second copy of the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another array/vector that contains the indices to the first array.

```
std::vector indices(size);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   indices[i] = i;
```

Then sort `indices` such that:

```
arr[indices[i]][0] <= arr[indices[i+1]][0]
```

After that, given an index `i`, you can find the element in `arr` using `arr[indices[i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer for C++, continuing from the comment, and for sake of completeness, a similar C solution using an array of pointers could look similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* qsort compare function for pointer array */
int cmp_pairs (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int *aa = *(int **)a;
    int *ab = *(int **)b;

    if (*aa < *ab)
        return -1;
    return (*ab < *aa);
}

int main (void) {

    /* original pairs array in b-sort order */
    int pairs[][2] = {{  12,   1 },
                      {  37,   2 },
                      {  41,   3 },
                      {  82,   4 },
                      {  29,   5 },
                      {  63,   6 },
                      {  78,   7 },
                      {  84,   8 },
                      {  67,   9 },
                      {  77,  10 }};
    size_t n = sizeof pairs/sizeof *pairs;
    size_t i = 0;
    int *pairs_a[n]; /* array of pointers for a-sort */

    /* fill pairs_a pointer array */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pairs_a[i] = pairs[i];

    /* sort pointer array based on a */
    qsort (pairs_a, n, sizeof *pairs_a, cmp_pairs);

    /* output both arrays */
    printf ("\n original array in b-sort order:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  { %3d, %3d }\n", pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);

    printf ("\n pointer array in a-sort order:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  { %3d, %3d }\n", pairs_a[i][0], pairs_a[i][1]);

    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**a-Sorted Output Maintaing Relationship**

```
$ ./bin/pairs_ab

 original array in b-sort order:

  {  12,   1 }
  {  37,   2 }
  {  41,   3 }
  {  82,   4 }
  {  29,   5 }
  {  63,   6 }
  {  78,   7 }
  {  84,   8 }
  {  67,   9 }
  {  77,  10 }

 pointer array in a-sort order:

  {  12,   1 }
  {  29,   5 }
  {  37,   2 }
  {  41,   3 }
  {  63,   6 }
  {  67,   9 }
  {  77,  10 }
  {  78,   7 }
  {  82,   4 }
  {  84,   8 }
```